# Not sure I understand iterator implementation

Tags: java, iterator

I'm supposed to implement an iterator for the:

```
public class BinaryHeap<AnyType extends Comparable<? super AnyType>> extends AbstractQueue<AnyType>
```

Class, and these are its attributes:

```
private static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 100;
private int currentSize;
private AnyType [ ] array;
private boolean min;
private int modifications; //AKA "modcount"
```

The two methods that I had to implement (override?) are `hasNext()` `next()`; in addition, my iterator has to be *fail-fast*. This is my attempt:

```
 private class HeapIterator implements Iterator
{
    int expectedModCount = modifications;
    int currentPosition;

    public boolean hasNext()
    {
        return currentPosition < array.length;
    }


    public Object next() throws NoSuchElementException, 
                    ConcurrentModificationException, 
                    UnsupportedOperationException
    {

        if (modifications != expectedModCount)
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        return array[currentPosition++];
    }

    public void remove()
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

But I showed it to a classmate and they said my `next()` and `hasNext()` functions aren't good but didn't have time to explain why. Any help?

Comment: Parametrize your `HeapIterator`.

Comment: It should probably do the generic thing, but otherwise this looks pretty good.

Comment: `next()` never throws `NoSuchElementException` or `UnsupportedOperationException`. But it does throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: To clarify what @shmosel said: next() should not throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. But it should throw NoSuchElementException if there is no next element.

Comment: Basically, just add `if (!hasNext()) throw new NoSuchElementException();` to `next()`.

Comment: Your `hasNext()` method should probably be checking `currentPosition` against `currentSize`, not `array.length`.